# How to use protobuf in my github actions?

Tags: cmake, github-actions, protocol-buffers

I have been developing a large C++ project on my mac. I am using CMake as the build system and googletest for testing.

Since I want the project to be multi-platform, I have been using Github actions to run my tests on windows and linux despite not owning a windows or linux computer.

Anyway, I started using protobuf to help with serialization of some of my structures. However, now my Github actions are all failing because none of the default Github action OS environments include protobuf. CMake is unable to find the necessary protobuf libraries, and thus fails.

Is there a simple solution for this problem? I imagine this situation has been encountered not just for protobuf.

I found this solution online, but was wondering if there is a simpler way.

https://lukasjoswiak.com/github-actions-protobuf/

The error I am getting on Github reads...

```
Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Which I believe stems from the lines...

```
include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: Can you not replicate the same steps in GHA workflow that you perform locally to build and test your project? What exactly is the error that you get in GHA? Please include that in your question. To install `protoc`, you can use https://github.com/arduino/setup-protoc action.

Comment: Let me try the setup-protoc action you linked. Locally, I have protoc installed on my machine, then I use `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` in my CMake file.

Comment: `protoc` is only the one part to compile your proto files. You need the C++ APIs (lib) as well to use the generated files. You can use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html) with Cmake for this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration. Depending on the target OS, you may have to adjust it a bit.

Comment: I would recommend to put these together on your local machine before configuring your GHA workflow. Having a working local build flow makes it much easier.

Comment: Ok, yes I am looking at vcpkg now. Definitely looks like an overall better way to manage dependencies for my project.